# What kind of server jack is this?

Tags: datacenter

In this video: http://vodpod.com/watch/2515104-rack-and-install-the-cisco-ucs-5108-server-chassis  3:18 into the video. I'm curious about Server Jacks and possibly ballpark costs for them.